# Dtd validation with libxml2

Tags: xml, dtd, libxml2

how do i do dtd validation with libxml2?
i am reading my xml file using the reader api.
i have an external dtd validation file.
how do i perform the validation itself?
do i have to convert it to xsd?

Comment: What 'host' language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xmlValidateDtd`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-valid.html#xmlValidateDtd) api, as described in [FAQ](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html), point 11.

This function is used by `xmllint` application, when `--dtdvalid` is supplied. See the source file, [`xmllint.c`](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xmllint.c), `parseAndPrintFile` function. Search for `xmlValidateDtd`, it's used only once now.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using python as your programming language, try using lxml. This has in-built implementation of libxml2 which is pretty neat in XML DTD validation. And it provides a lot of information which can be helpful in debugging the dtd or xml file.